# How do we solve the package installation problem?

Tags: discussion, answer-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post links that install software via apt?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)

I had a friend try stackexchange and he was disappointed that a bunch of the easier commands (like recommending installing applications) was still too complicated for someone like his father.

There is a service called apt.ubuntu.com that prompts the user to install something from the software center, for example:

You should [install Banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee/).

The link I used here is `https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee/` This works for anything in the archive!

If you're using Firefox and/or Chromium/Chrome this launches the Ubuntu Software Center.

I think it's probably a good idea to get on an agreed-to convention earlier before it's too late to go back and update everything when we grow.