# Should the welcome message put more focus on casual users?

Tags: discussion, scope

Hi, I was wondering whether we should change the site welcome message (the one that pops up in the bar at the top) to say "Welcome to the QA site for Ubuntu users", rather than "...users and developers", in the attempt to put more focus on the daily problems of non-technical users, rather than complex development issues?

A good example of such technical bias causing problems for some users: [How do we solve the package installation problem?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/the-package-installation-problem)

Answer (score 3):

I actually prefer the way it's laid out, because the site's aim is for authoritative answers for the Ubuntu Family (users, developers, and community). Driving out developers may close the scope of the site so much that it becomes less effective. I remember reading somewhere ( I believe it was on the Area 51 site ) about how the name was moved from "QA site for Ubuntu" to "...users and developers"

Much like StackOverflow has questions for all different languages supporting questions for all different walks of life in the Ubuntu family seems most beneficial.

Comment: Yes but it's not driving developers away as much as it's welcoming new users and letting them know we can help. Developers asking "How do I rebuild a package from source?" will likely come to SE through google, no?

Comment: We shouldn't drive the developers away, as they usually have the most expertise to answer Ubuntu-related questions. But I think we should concentrate on helping users that have less technical expertise. In that sense, the site is "for the users", as much as the Ubuntu technical documentation is "for the developers". It is obvious that everyone is equally welcome to use the site.

Comment: And, worth remembering, Ubuntu developers are also Ubuntu users :)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like a solution in search of a problem. I don't see "users" as more welcoming terminology than "users and developers" for the typical user, nor do I see it as capable of driving off developers who are also users. As you state in [your comment,](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/390/should-the-welcome-message-put-more-focus-on-casual-users?rq=1#comment499_394)It is obvious that everyone is equally welcome to use the site. (For Ubuntu related Q & A)