# Software package installation Icon

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the software icon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1917/change-the-software-icon)

In regards to [The package installation problem.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/the-package-installation-problem) it's become clear we would like to add a custom launching icon that can be used to open the apt.ubuntu.com URL - allowing packages to be easily installed and obscurifying any command-line or complicated package installation options to more novice users.

Please submit one example Icon per rely including a 16x16 icon (and 24x24 icon if possible) also any SVG of the image and source of the image would be desired.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1917/change-the-software-icon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The existing Software Center icons are already used to convey that you install stuff from it, so I think we should use those:

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are possibly [out of date](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/398/software-package-installation-icon/2035#2035).

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer the standard "package with arrow pointing down icon." I think it is much more relevant to the action that the user will be doing. The software center icon conveys the idea of a place where many different things can be found, while this icon shows that you will be downloading a package

[image: 16]

[image: 24]

These are from Humanity (/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/16/system-software-installer.svg). Although, I actually like the ones with the orange arrow [in this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/the-package-installation-problem/395#395) better. I'm just not sure where they come from.

Comment: The orange icons were actually modified from `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/16/update-manager.svg` the icon for which was originally suggested by Oli in chat. I modified the arrow to make them more "download" suggested.

Answer (score 3):

These are modified from the `update-manager` icon in the Humanity Theme.

[image: 16x16]

[image: 24x24]

I've uploaded the SVG [here](http://marcoceppi.com/u.se/download-icon.svg)

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Stolen from [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1917/change-the-software-icon/1922#1922) to a [similar question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1917/18612), these icons are similar to the new Ubuntu Software Center icon used in 11.10:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's also the Software Centre logo (as opposed to icon)

16px: [image: 16px Version of Software Centre Logo] and 24px: [image: 24px Version of Software Centre Logo]

[SVG version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ubuntu_Software_Center_icon.svg) (GPL license according to Wikimedia Commons)

Probably not preferable to the icons specially created to look good at a small size, but it is more colourful and interesting...

Answer (score 0):

From the Tango Desktop Project:

[image: 16x16]

[image: 24x24]

SVG can be obtained from the [Tango Desktop Project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library)

(In Ubuntu this icon used to be used in the menu entry for Add/Remove Applications before the Software Centre was created)

Answer (score -3):

I believe the Ubiquity install Icon is one that's recognizable as an "Installation" of something:

[image: 16x16]

[image: 24x24]

From `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/24/ubiquity.svg`