# Change the software icon

Tags: discussion, icon

I've been working to [resolve this software icon issue](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1852/software-centre-image-link-is-broken), this will likely require a large find/replace on the site. In 11.10 the software icon was revised, going forward should we use that icon for the software links?

Please vote below.

Comment: The new icon is in /usr/share/icons/hicolo/16x16/apps/softwarecenter.svg btw

Comment: Not just on the site, on other SE sites (at least [unix.se] and [su]) as well. I don't mind what the icon looks like as long as we get something that works for everybody and we don't need to edit thousands of posts manually.

Comment: What about this: http://imgur.com/fw46j.png

Comment: @GeorgeEdison That was voted out last time

Comment: @JorgeCastro  Looks like you dropped the 'r' from hicolor for `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/softwarecenter.svg `

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/398/software-package-installation-icon

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes

These are cooler

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -5):

## No

These icons are fine:

[image]

[image]