# Should the question on Application Indicators be updated to include whether they work with 12.04?

Tags: discussion, answers

I request that [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) be "refreshed" to show which indicators are still being maintained and usable in 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - I fully agree with you ... its a community wiki and thus its up-to the Ask Ubuntu community, that includes both yourself and myself to go through the answers and update them to include the most up-to date information.

Can I suggest - for those indicators that are not yet 12.04 compatible that the answer includes with the version(s) they work with - for example:

Install from PPA (11.04/11.10/12.04) - `ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily` and install package `indicator-multiload`

or

[`indicator-multiload`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-multiload)[image: Install indicator-multiload] in Ubuntu Software Centre (for 12.04 only)

Where the indicator can be installed from the software-center:

[Change the software icon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1917/change-the-software-icon)

for example:

Happy editing!

Comment: So far, I have made two comments in that "wiki". One is in the main question. The other is for the System Load Indicator in which I mentioned that it is now available from USC.

Comment: Please check out my edit for the System Load Indicator and comment on what should be the best way to include things like "10.04/11.10/12.04".

Comment: Do edits in the wiki not require approval? Mine seems to have been accepted pretty quick?

Comment: How do we handle cases which we **think** aren't available for 12.04? Case in point: `Hardware Sensors Indicator`.

Comment: see my edit - community-wiki answers require a lower rep threshold to edit - hence this is why you can edit.

Comment: How does one link an image to the url ??? I'm new to all this!

Comment: Click the edit hyperlink  on this answer - you can see the syntax that I have used - just change the bits for the indicator - pop into the general chat room if in doubt - we can talk you through this more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance but it's bed-time in my part of the world :( so I'm off before doing any more damage.