# Add support for apt:// link schema

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Instead of having to remember the whole `apt.ubuntu.com/p/package` shebang, it would be easier to just support `apt://package` links.

Comment: IIRC Marco was talking to SE about doing `?packagename` and having that translate server side to the apt.ubuntu.com ...

Comment: @Jorge I like that idea (especially since you could have it expand to the full package name etc.) but wouldn't that particular syntax get in the way of people accidentally missing the space after the question mark? (You have my full support for, e.g., `?[text](package)`.)

Comment: The format being proposed is ?[package]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we solve the package installation problem?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/how-do-we-solve-the-package-installation-problem)

Answer (score 4):

apt.ubuntu.com currently doesn't have the nicest UI in the world, but https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptUrlRedirector suggests more how it *should* work. I hope I'll get some time to actually implement nicer screens on apt.ubuntu.com to make it more worthwhile to link to.

Comment: The HTTP 426 response is priceless :)

Comment: Improvements to the AptUrlRedirector can be found on the [LanchPad Page](https://launchpad.net/apturlredirector)

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that apt:// protocol links are deprecated.  These provide a terrible experience on non-Ubuntu platforms, with no further explanation of what Ubuntu is and how they can get the software they just clicked the aforementioned link for.

Granted, apt.ubuntu.com currently suffers this problem as well, but it is my hope that its authors will use the free advertising space it provides to start a conversation with non-Ubuntu users.

Comment: apt:// bot working on non-Ununtu systems shouldn't be an issue as this Ask Ubuntu is targeted for Ubuntu users.

Comment: But it is important to make all links uniform, for simplicity, be it on Ask Ubuntu or Loco Teams' wikis, etc.