# Make apt-links clickable.

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Add support for apt:// link schema](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/443/add-support-for-apt-link-schema)
>   [How to post links that install software via apt?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)

It's a shame that we have to tell people to "sudo apt-get install packagename" on AskUbuntu.com. It should be sufficient to provide apt://packagename and let the user just click it to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are several options for posters to generate their links as links that will open the software centre.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt) The basis behind all of them is linking to `http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/<package-name>`.

There have been discussions about making this automatic (eg to detect `apt-get install ...`) but my attempt to do this failed. The major problem is you'll also see `add-apt-repository` scattered around the site and this can be a major part to getting some things working. Adding apt repos is not possible via a link (for good reason!).

Comment: if that's the case then how do they do this (number 7)  : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair ? at least let us link and we can decide if we're going to use the link or not after having tested it to see if it works. It's too good a feature to shun. Another thing : this question says duplicate ok then which is the original?