# How to post links that integrate with the Software Center?

Tags: support, apturl

There are some posts with nice Software Center icons and links to software installation via apt. How to do that?

Answer (score 48):

> ### Volunteers Wanted!
>
> Here is a search of posts with "sudo apt-get install" but are missing apps.ubuntu.com links (we filter out "error" and "ppa"). If you want to make a difference for new users, add these buttons to existing questions **where appropriate!**
>
> - https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+%22sudo+apt-get+install%22+-apps.ubuntu.com+-error+-ppa+-hot+-closed
>
> Note: If the only app(s) referenced in a particular post are CLI-only, adding a prominent Download button seems redundant - they're going to open a terminal anyway. In that case, or if putting the download button might ruin the formatting/flow, e.g. in a multi-step post, please consider using the less-obtrusive inline image/link.

This is the official download button from Ubuntu, promoted [here](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/06/06/download-for-ubuntu-button-campaign/):

[image: Install via the software center]

Copy this and edit it for the package you want and paste it into an answer:

```
[![Install via the software center](https://hostmar.co/software-banner)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee)
```

---

Or like this when you want an inline app link:

[banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [image: Install banshee]

```
[banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [![Install banshee](https://hostmar.co/software-small)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee)
```

---

If you want a larger inline link (heading size) you can use this:

## [banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [image: Install banshee]

```
#[banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [![Install banshee](https://hostmar.co/software-large)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee)
```

---

- Nathan Osman has a [script here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2405/insert-apt-link-making-it-easy-to-insert-an-apt-link-into-your-question-answ) that adds a button to the Ask Ubuntu formatting toolbar. (Get this if you plan on doing this, it makes it so easy).
- Note, apps.ubuntu.com is the officialish way to link up applications in the software center as it has fallback for non-Ubuntu users, like this: `https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee/`
- apt.ubuntu.com will still work and is fine, so we don't need to go redit every question, but new posts moving forward should use apps.u.c.

Comment: 167 pages of questions needing awesome edits: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=body%3A%22apt-get+install%22&submit=search

Comment: @BrunoPereira 4 years later: 5,099 results.

Comment: The small image is broken. Anything we can do about that?  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16709/plenty-of-broken-image-links

Comment: @Seth [hostmar.co](http://hostmar.co) links now redirect to imgur, but all posts should be updated on small [from this](http://hostmar.co/software-small) to  [this](https://i.imgur.com/uRtxs.png) and on large [from this](http://hostmar.co/software-large) to [this](https://i.imgur.com/ceZqJ.png).

Comment: @Pablo no, the reason for the hostmar redirect is so that we can change the icon if we need/want to.

Comment: @Seth OK, but since hostmar.co doesn't implement HTTPS, how we should avoid the "All image URLs must start with https://
Upload to imgur or specify an HTTPS URL" red message every time you edit a post with those links?

Comment: @Pablo ah, that is an issue. I will contact Marco and see if he can't set HTTPS up.

Comment: It implements https now.

Comment: Canonical seems to have broken apps.ubuntu.com without any announcements. This answer is now out-of-date.

Answer (score 29):

A simple script that prompts for package name and copy the formatted code to your clipboard:

```
#!/bin/bash

PACKAGE=$(zenity --entry --text="packagename")
echo "#[${PACKAGE}](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/${PACKAGE}) [![Install ${PACKAGE}](https://hostmar.co/software-large)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications${PACKAGE})" | xclip
```

Make sure you install [xclip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xclip) [image: Install xclip]

Comment: Canonical seems to have broken apps.ubuntu.com without any announcements. This answer is now out-of-date.

Answer (score 15):

*This is a partial solution for people who don't use Firefox, so can't use the new addon. I can confirm it works for Chromium 6.*

You can use browser bookmarks with 'javascript:' URLs to insert the correct markdown into the answer box.

**Bookmark 1:**

Name: `APT Linker Big`

URL: `javascript:(function (pkg) {document.getElementById('wmd-input').innerHTML += "#[" +pkg +"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/" +pkg +") [![Install " +pkg +'](https://hostmar.co/software-large)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/' +pkg +')';})(prompt("Enter the package name to link to it."));`

Clicking on this will insert the markdown for a software package link in the title.

**Bookmark 2:**

Name: `Apt Linker Small`

URL: `javascript:(function (pkg) {document.getElementById('wmd-input').innerHTML += "[" +pkg +"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/" +pkg +") [![Install " +pkg +'](https://hostmar.co/software-small)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/' +pkg +')';})(prompt("Enter the package name to link to it."));`

Clicking on this will insert the markdown for a software package link in the text.

There is a problem with this: If you enter text then delete it and press one of the bookmarks, your deleted text will mysteriously appear.

On Chrome/Chromium, you can add these bookmarks by right clicking on the bookmarks bar and clicking 'Add Page'. You can toggle the visibility of the bookmarks bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
[image: add bookmark]

**DEMO**

## [hello](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hello) [image: Install hello]

[hello](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hello) [image: Install hello]

Answer (score 13):

For reference, the source syntax for a package called NAME is
`[NAME](http://packages.ubuntu.com/NAME) [![Install NAME](https://hostmar.co/software-small)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/NAME)`
(for titles, there is also `software-large`).

Other answers show various means of automation that generate this from the name you enter.

Answer (score 9):

> ### Note:
>
> This tool has been superseeded by [this UserScript](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/au_toolbar.user.js) which offers the same functionality but adds some additional features and integrates better with the editing toolbar.

### Insert Apt Link

This small UserScript adds a button to the editing toolbar that makes it easy to insert a link to an APT package. Simply click on the button and type the name of the package.

[image: Screenshot]

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/apt.user.js

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome 11 - should work on Firefox and Opera as well.

#### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

#### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think this is something that should be fixed editorially, that is to say: us.

We would spend weeks changing `apt-gets`, holding debates over whether a question is server- or desktop- orientated and it still might not be easier for somebody to install multiple packages the way `sudo apt-get package-1 package-2 package-3` can.

Picking one or other isn't going to make everybody happy and enforcing it isn't going to make our lives any easier.

However, I'm not saying this isn't a feature we should leverage. Would it not make a certain amount of sense to have a little bit of javascript (and it *would* be quite small) that searched the page for `apt-get install xxx` and replaced `xxx` with a link to apt.ubuntu.com, or added an icon next to it that users could click to install.

In the same vein, we could do something with JS that just made a link direct to `apt://xxx` but apturl could do with some attention to make it work a little prettier.

**To deal with PPAs** up until now I've been writing it out as a command using `add-apt-repository`. A similar JS-search/replace thing could be used here but it would only serve as a help box to show the user a non-CLI method of adding the repo.

**And while we're at it,** we could have something that replaced -->, -> with ▸ (per the unified  style guides).

These are all things we'd need to sort out with StackOverflow but they're trivially easy that I can't see them having a problem with them.

Answer (score 4):

You could use apt:// protocol links, which would open with the apturl package.  It sounds like apturl is installed by default, and doesn't depend on any browser-specific extensions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL

Answer (score 3):

Since this thread just popped back up, it reminded me that I made a small change to the above script that is worth sharing. I realized that I'm normally calling the script (which I call `ask-link` BTW) from the command line or the `Alt-F2` run dialog. So the zenity dialog is a bit redundant. So I first check to see if a package name is passed when calling the script and only show the dialog if it isn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Create link for installing packages on AskUbuntu. Source:
# http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt

if [ -n "$1" ]; then 
    PACKAGE=$1
else
    PACKAGE=$(zenity --entry --text="packagename")
fi

echo "[${PACKAGE}](http://packages.ubuntu.com/${PACKAGE}) [![Install ${PACKAGE}](http://hostmar.co/software-large)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/${PACKAGE})" | xclip
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.0.1 of AskUbuntu Add-on will come with such functionality.

http://askubuntu-extension.blogspot.com/2010/10/new-features-coming-soon.html

Answer (score 2):

It's nice to have an easy install link for packages, but I'd rather have it link to a short page with the package description, which in turn has an easy install link. I think there's a danger in making the process too transparent.

Is there an alternative service to the standard [package search site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) which doesn't make one pick a distribution version first, and has an [apturl](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL)?