# How can I add a link within an answer on AskUbuntu.com to download a package?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post links that install software via apt?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)

I want to create a link in my answers that automatically open the Ubuntu Software Store with that package pulled up. I've gone through the FAQ, Ask Ubuntu questions, and Googled it as well.

Comment: Questions like this go on meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt