# Understanding apt.ubuntu.com and its use in askubuntu

Tags: discussion, support, answer-format, answers

I have noticed in a number of answers to questions where the use of the apt.ubuntu.com (I think this is what I recall) is employed to assist with the installation of some Ubuntu package that may not be installed by default.  I think that the example I saw was http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager.

1. How does one use this apt.ubuntu.com URL to effectively communicate a package requiring installation before the given answer is able to be invoked?
2. Is this something that folks have access to as they achieve greater reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can use apt links, here you go!

- [How to post links that integrate with the Software Center?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)

Comment: Thanks, @Jorge.  Your help is much appreciated.