# How can we participate in the Ubuntu Global Jam?

Tags: discussion, community, site-promotion

Welcome [Ubuntu Global Jammers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGlobalJam)!

Thanks for taking the time to check out tasks for Ask Ubuntu. We've put together a list of things that should help you get started.

and then submit an edit, then it will go into the queue and you'll earn 2 points for each edit. Once you feel comfortable how the site works you can start to tackle answering questions. Of course, if you're new to Ubuntu you can participate just by asking questions to things you want to know!

Some of the tasks require certain amount of points (to weed out spammers), so just submit a few edits to get the hang of it and then you should get enough points to start to be able to do things like attaching screenshots.

You should check out the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) if you've never been here before, and feel free to pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you need help.

Answer (score 6):

### Things to Do!

#### Ask and Answer questions

This is what the site's all about, though editing and improving content over time is important, this is our bread and butter:

- New here and know Ubuntu? You can dive right into the [unanswered questions](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes).
- If you're already used the site before, then feel free to dive into the [unanswered questions](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags), these are tailored for tags you have answered in the past.

#### Editing existing content

This is great for people who know how to copy edit and proofread, but might not be Ubuntu experts, you can learn a bunch just by helping fix spelling and grammar mistakes and by retitleing questions to be easier to read. Just click on "improve this post"

[image]

- Going through our [top questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions) and our [FAQ questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq) (yes, there will be overlap) and making sure they are up-to-date for Precise.
- Go through the [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag and spruce up all the screenshots/add them/update them/etc.
- [Tumbleweeds](https://askubuntu.com/badges/40/tumbleweed) - these are questions that got low views and little attention, can they be improved/edited to be more useful?
- [Famous](https://askubuntu.com/badges/28/famous-question), [Notable](https://askubuntu.com/badges/27/notable-question), and [Popular Questions](https://askubuntu.com/badges/26/popular-question): These get higher traffic than most questions, check them to see if they can be updated for 12.04
- [Low quality posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=month), can they be improved?
- Search for people posting man pages and link them to: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/
- When people recommend software link it to app.ubuntu.com: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/235
- Go through an ambiguous tag and replace the ambiguous tag with a more descriptive tag which will be provided.
- Look at our [greatest hits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/greatest-hits) and make sure they are as high quality as possible.

#### Experienced Users

- We could use a hand with [review](https://askubuntu.com/review).

#### Tips and Tricks

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks