# How do you add an apt-link to an askubuntu question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post links that install software via apt?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)

I was answering a question and I wanted to add a direct link to a package using the apt: format but the askubuntu told me the link is invalid. Is there a way to add this kind of link to an askubuntu question?

Comment: See also: http://stackapps.com/questions/2405/ask-ubuntu-toolbar-buttons-a-set-of-toolbar-buttons-for-ask-ubuntu-that-make-i for a menu option.

Comment: Yup, seems like a duplicate of 548 but since that's in a different domain I can't mark this as a duplicate of it. Any ideas on how to solve this?