# Which Software Center install button should we use?

Tags: discussion

The current Software Center download button is something like this, promoted [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/548/176889):

http://hostmar.co/software-banner
<sub>(This seems to be newer in style and colouring, with regards to the Ubuntu theme.)</sub>

however, a different button seems to be in use, seen on http://apps.ubuntu.com:

[image]

Which button should be used?
Is one preferred over the other (and why)?

---

**Example:** [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/408609/176889) used the apps.ubuntu.com icon, whereas almost every other answer used the first button shown above.

Comment: ah I know why... I aint using Ubuntu atm :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, [the one that uses the accepted short-link](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/449). That post links to the images through the `hostmar.co` domain (which is run by Marco). **We need to keep doing that.**

The reason this is so important is that if the images die/change in the future, Marco can just sneeze on the server and BOOM, updated URL all over the entire site without needing to beg SE to find-and-replace through their database.

If you see somebody using a different image, replace it and cite this post (or that post, or both).

Answer (score 2):

The red one! It is brighter and seems more polished. And another META about this has the red one: [How to post links that integrate with the Software Center?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-integrate-with-the-software-center)

But these seem to have 2 meanings. How I see them: the 1st one could automatically start the download. The 2nd one implies you go to another website and then have to download what is to be downloaded. So it might be worth it to use both based on how you want to like to the download.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the red one looks nicer. The meanings may be slightly misleading, though, neither actually auto-starts the download. Using the orange one may be confusing because the button says "on the Software Center" whereas if you click it, you're taken to apps.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score -1):

The second one (personal openion)! That seems a bit darker but more close to the Ubuntu orange (as specified in Ubuntu's Brand Assets). While the other one is far from this (but seems that's what recommended by Jono Bacon, Ubuntu Community Manager, in his [website](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/06/06/download-for-ubuntu-button-campaign/) as linked by Oli in his post) and looks somewhat a blend of the community-feel Ubuntu Orange and commercial-indicating Canonical Aubergine, and may be that's the intention - cover both community and commercial software packages with that shade ?!

1: Ubuntu Orange - Canonical Aubergine blend:

[image: snap1]

2: The colour palette:

[image: snap2]

<sup>*([source: pic 2](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette))*</sup>

Button1
[image: pic1]

Button2
[image: pic2]

Some [guidelines](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo) for correct use of Ubuntu logo; you must not…

> Change the spacing between the individual elements or characters
>
> Change the colour of the wordmark
>
> Change the colour of the Circle of Friends
>
> Change the arrangement of the elements
>
> Place the logo at an angle other than horizontal or vertical
>
> Change the proportion of the logo
>
> Place the logo on a non brand colour

Some easily noticed features in the compared buttons:

- Ubuntu Orange? Or Orange? [Button1 - ???; Button2 + orange blends]
- [Colour of Circle of Friends](https://design.ubuntu.com/downloads?metadata=element-logo%20brand-ubuntu)? [Button1 - ???; Button2 + white]
- Roundel? It's colour? [Button1 + white; Button2 - ???]
- Looks good? [Button1 + Y; Button2 - ?]

<sub>Something probably needs an update..</sub>

Comment: See [Oli's answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8138/44179).