# Alternative to apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion

This is a follow-up to my answer and the corresponding question: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17148/420786. What is a viable alternative to apps.ubuntu.com?

Comment: I have used this one a few times https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ or of course https://packages.ubuntu.com/ is always a good choice.

Comment: Do we really need one? Isn't it enough to either give the `apt install` command or just the name of the program which can be found in the software center?

Comment: @terdon that is what i mean by an alternative :D

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain why an alternative is needed? The link tells me that apps.ubuntu.com is outdated, but I'd like to see that information in the question itself

Answer (score 7):

I personally typically refer to Ubuntu Packages Search located at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as mentioned by Mark Kirby in [this comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17188/alternative-to-apps-ubuntu-com#comment35470_17188) Thus far I've found the information to be up to date covering all supported versions of Ubuntu. By crafting the search properly it can also help future proof your answer as shown in [this ffmpeg search.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg)

The inclusion of suite=all in the search returns results for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Of course you can specify the release if the question you are answering is version specific as in [suite=xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg) for 16.04, etc.