# What do we do about the links to apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion

For years now, [we have added links to apps.ubuntu.com with pretty little icons and banners](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/548/158442). Recent consensus is that [we should stop adding those links](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17148/158442) (I agree).

However, the existing links had at least some value, until now. Their target pages used to have buttons with the `apt://` URLs, so even if the site didn't have recent releases, visitors could have conceivably used those buttons to install the software.

No longer:

```
$ curl -I https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 11:22:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://snapcraft.io/store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The redirection makes no attempt to use the original URL, so users who click on such links are faced with a search page:

[image]

I think this makes for terrible UX.

As I see it, we don't have many options. We can:

1. remove such URLs as we come across them

   1. or go on a rampage
2. ask SE to mass-remove them (not likely to happen, but probably worth a shot)
3. ask Canonical to use the package name as a search term:

   ```
   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc ->
   https://snapcraft.io/search?q=vlc
   ```

   This way, the links retain some marginal utility (though I assume the vast majority of "applications" on apps.ubuntu.com haven't become snaps).
4. Change these to `http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/...` (as suggested by @dessert). There are [~1500 posts with this URL](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=url%3Aapt.ubuntu.com) vs [~2800 posts with apps.ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=url%3Aapps.ubuntu.com).

   1. Possibly by asking either SE to do so or Canonical to change the redirect.

Thoughts?

Comment: I didn’t even notice I used a different link, but `http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/PACKAGE`, e.g. `http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sl` works like a charm – maybe we just replace the links? Or maybe replace with `apt` links directly, if that works? I consider this feature **very** useful, we should not remove, but rather **replace** the links IMHO!

Comment: @dessert added that as an option. But that domain doesn't do HTTPS, I think.

Comment: Not evereybody (me) may want to direct people to snaps

Comment: I cannot access `apt.ubuntu.com`. It just replies with an empty response.

Comment: P.S. Suggestion: simply change the links to `apt://` links.

Comment: This is a great example (spanning the whole stack exchange network) on why links to external websites should be discouraged and minimized, because even seemingly "reputable" websites will eventually break their URIs even though it's not [cool to do so](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

Comment: @pipe links to external resources are generally OK *provided that the answer summarizes their content* (adding a link is also good so the Wayback Machine gets another chance to crawl it). Unfortunately APT links are not summarized, probably we should just point to `apt://`.

Comment: +1 1.1. *rampage*