# Mobile view adds linebreaks before and after images even if they are very small

Tags: bug, design, site-attributes

If my answer uses a package one has to install first, I like to add an AptURL link with the small package symbol [image], e.g. for `sl` using this:

```
[`sl` ![Install sl](https://hostmar.co/software-small)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sl)
```

Essentially that’s the way the canonical meta post shows it: [How to post links that integrate with the Software Center?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/548/507051)

The output should look like [image: normal output] and does that in the normal “full site” mode, but if you switch to the “Mobile” version (by clicking “Mobile” at the bottom of the page on the left), instead it looks like this:

[image: odd mobile output]

Apparently the image is centered on a new line, which makes it look really weird. You can observe this behaviour on [said canonical post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/507051), just switch to the mobile view to see the effect.