# askubuntu should introduce a apt link button.

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The package installation problem.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/the-package-installation-problem)

just like the http link button and image button askubuntu should have a apt link buttom which asks for the package and automatically links it with http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/PACKAGE_NAME the site by marcoceppi works in all browsers and is more descriptive.

Comment: apt.marcoceppi.com is planned to replace apt.ubuntu.com hopefully before the release of Natty

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67401/can-se-sites-have-custom-additions-to-their-post-markup and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57673/support-for-site-specific-formatting-hooks-in-se2-0-sites