# Way nicer software installation than we have now, should we do this?

Tags: discussion, answer-format

I saw this today and it's awesome, as seen here: https://askubuntu.com/a/124747/235

I like this better than our small icon because this one looks clickable and will do what you expect it to do instead of the little orange bag.

I know Marco controls the shortlink to the image, but I don't think we could just swap them out, so for your consideration, I think using this would be a huge improvement for our new-user questions and would tie AU better with the USC experience

References:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/how-do-we-solve-the-package-installation-problem

---

Banshee is great, you should install it:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: An associated question: Should we link to apt.ubuntu.com or apps.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Thanks mentioning my answer ,I used this in other answer also , I tried to give direct link ubuntu software centre instead of linking to apps.ubuntu.com But it did'nt work :(, Once I decided to post it here but I forgot

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards Ok so dpm tells me we should use apps.ubuntu.com because that also takes into account when people are not on ubuntu systems, and is the official blessed way to send people there, so I'll go ahead and fix that up.

Comment: I'd suggest linking to apps.ubuntu.com, since it provides a nice landing page where users can learn more about the app, read the reviews and install it. It is also a platform-independent fallback, since you first land on a webpage regardless of the OS, as opposed to apt.ubuntu.com throwing an error if you're not using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great alternative. as it sells the branding for Ubuntu Software Center better, as well as serves as a better Call to Action. I'm all for this as an improvement to the current button. However, I don't think it'll work as a drop-in replacement given the current structure of the markup for the button.

It would be great to add it to the current package installation post as the suggested button in addition to amending the current user script to have this as an option.