# how to add a link that will open the software center

Tags: discussion, support

I have added link to apps.ubuntu.com by providing a button to click on till now...

But neither by the method -

"[package name] (link)" and nor by assign a url to the button image,i could give a direct link to start the software center.

I have found out by inspecting the javascript og other sites and apps.ubuntu.com that the url that the button leads to is

**apt://packagename**

but when i use it,

in the "[package name] (link)" method the link is not created at all and

in the button method the button does not remain a button an becomes just a simple image.

and neither is my answer accepted if i put just **apt://packagename** as the link behind the button.

It says invalid url or something..

How do i get it working.??The Button one specially...

Comment: Isn't this a regular Ask Ubuntu question rather than a question for meta?

Comment: Its about providing links etc ON ask-ubuntu...on ask-ubuntu we ask ubuntu related questions and on meta we ask ask-ubuntu related questions rite??

Comment: link and image with the scrips posted in [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1405/47206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URIs on the internet go like this:

```
<scheme name>://<hierarchical path>?<query>

(eg) http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest
```

There are dozens of URI scheme names in use; the most popular are `http` and `https`, but `irc`, `geo`, `git`, and `apt` are some examples of alternatives.

As far as I know, Stack Exchange (our Q&A engine) only allows `http` and `https` URIs. As such, your `apt://` URLS will not be accepted in posts. This is unlikely to change. [Ask Ubuntu community consensus recommends linking to packages for installation like this.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/how-do-we-solve-the-package-installation-problem)